# Javascript | Generate an array of times based on a start and an end

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

I am trying to generate a dynamic array based on 2 different times which are in the 24 hours format. For example, start: 12:00, ends: 22:00.

I've tried the solution below, however it doesn't cater for what I need as I have a string representation of the start number.

```js
const startTime = '12:00'
const endTime = '22:00'

var x = 30; //minutes interval
var times = []; // time array
var tt = 0; // start time
var ap = ['AM', 'PM']; // AM-PM

for (var i=0;tt<24*60; i++) {
  var hh = Math.floor(tt/60); // getting hours of day in 0-24 format
  var mm = (tt%60); // getting minutes of the hour in 0-55 format
  times[i] = ("0" + (hh % 12)).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + mm).slice(-2) + ap[Math.floor(hh/12)]; // pushing data in array in [00:00 - 12:00 AM/PM format]
  tt = tt + x;
}

console.log(times);
```

I am looking for the interval to be 30 minutes and the end result be the following:

```
[
    '12:00 PM', '12:30 PM', '01:00 PM', '01:30 PM', '01:00 PM', '01:30 PM',
    ...
    '09:00 PM', '09:30 PM', '09:00 PM'
]
```

If I change the tt (start_time) on the solution above then I get the following data:

```
['12:12 PM', '01:12 PM']
```

Comment: where is start time and end time? why am/pm, if oyu like to get 24 h time? what about the interval? where do you get this from? what does not work with the code? can you move it to stack snippets?

Comment: Hi Nina, I"ve updated the question sorry, to include a snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you could use `Array.from` and use the index to build the time string:

```js
function getTimes(start, end) {
    // Convert to number of half-hours
    start = parseInt(start) * 2 + (+start.slice(-2) > 0);
    end = parseInt(end) * 2 + (+end.slice(-2) > 0) + 1;
    // Produce series
    return Array.from({length: end - start}, (_, i) =>
        (((i + start) >> 1) + ":" + ((i + start)%2*3) + "0").replace(/^\d:/, "0$&"));
};

console.log(getTimes("9:30", "22:30"));
```

If you need AM/PM formatted output:

```js
function getTimes(start, end) {
    start = parseInt(start) * 2 + (+start.slice(-2) > 0);
    end = parseInt(end) * 2 + (+end.slice(-2) > 0) + 1;
    return Array.from({length: end - start}, (_, i) => 
        [i + start >> 1, (i + start)%2*30]
    ).map(([h, m]) => 
        `${h % 12 || 12}:${m} ${"AP"[+(h > 11)]}M`.replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&")
    );
}

console.log(getTimes("9:30", "22:30"));
```

### Explanation

`parseInt(start)` will turn the given string to a number, parsing it up to the point it finds an "invalid" character, which will be the colon. So `parseInt("19:30")` will evaluate to 19.

`+start.slice(-2)` will get the last two characters from the string and convert that to a number -- using the unary plus operator. `parseInt` would also work, but since we don't expect an invalid character here, it is shorter (and more efficient) to use `+`. So for "19:30" this will evaluate to 30.

`(+start.slice(-2) > 0)` will evaluate to a boolean (false or true) depending on whether the minutes are 0 or not. So if the minutes part is 30, this expression evaluates to true. As it is used in a numeric expression (using addition), this boolean will coerce into a number (0 or 1).

Combining those elements, the whole expression `parseInt(start) * 2 + (+start.slice(-2) > 0)` will calculate the number of half-hours that passed since midnight.

So the first two lines of the function will transform `start` and `end` from "99:99" format to a number of half-hours. Note that 1 half hour extra is counted for `end`, so that time itself is *included*.

Then we create an array whose size is the number of half hours between `start` and `end`: `Array.from({length: end - start})`. The interesting thing of `Array.from` is that it takes a callback function with which each entry in that array can be initialised. I decided to initialise each entry with a pair of values: hour and minute. This pair is thus an array with two elements.

The hour part is `i + start >> 1`. Since `i + start` represents the number of half-hours, it needs to be divided by 2 to get the number of hours. `>>1` is ideal for this, as it performs an integer division by 2. `Math.floor((i + start) / 2)` would also work, but is longer ;-).

The minute part is `(i + start)%2*30`: The remainder operator (`%`) will give us the remainder of a division by 2. That remainder is either 0 or 1, and tells us whether the minutes part should be 0 or 30. By multiplying with 30 we get that number of minutes.

Once that array is created, we get an intermediate result that might look like this:

```
[
    [9, 30],
    [10, 0],
    [10, 30],
    [11, 0],
    [11, 30],
    [12, 0],
    [12, 30],
    [13, 0],
]
```

This still needs to be mapped to time *strings* in "99:99 PM" format. So we apply another `.map` to it. Each pair `[h, m]` is mapped to such a string:

`h % 12 || 12` will convert the hour part to a value in the range 1-12. The remainder operator already maps hours to the range 0-11, but in the final notation we should not have a 0, and the `|| 12` will kick in to turn that 0 in a 12 (because 0 is "falsy").

`"AP"[+(h > 11)]` will first get a boolean (false or true) that tells us whether `h` is greater than 11 (which means it is in the PM-range). That boolean is coerced to a number, using the unary plus, and so we get a 0 or a 1. This is in turn used as an index is a string "AP", so that the result will be either "A" or "P".

Taking those parts together, the expression `` `${h % 12 || 12}:${m} ${"AP"[+(h > 11)]}M` `` evaluates to a nice AM/PM notation. One thing remains:

The resulting string may include numbers that only have one digit. This we can find and replace with a regular expression: `/\b\d\b/` will find a digit that is in isolation. The replacement will reproduce that found digit with `$&`, but it also prepends that with a "0".

Comment: Hi Trincot, thanks for this, the only thing is it doesn't take into consideration the start and end time and it looks like this is just a straight 24 hour one

Comment: You want a function that takes these two arguments? OK, I'll update this in a sec.

Comment: Yes please, in the format of a string though like '12:00', '22:00'

Comment: Let me know if the updated snippet does what you need.

Comment: I added a variant with AM/PM formatted output.

Comment: it works perfectly, however, if you wouldn't mind would you put an explanation on how this works? I'm trying to figure out but keep getting slightly confused but would like to know how it works! Many thanks.

Comment: Added an explanation of the second snippet.